# angularjs add white space in ng-model

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have this `<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" class="step-input" placeholder="NAME*" readonly="readonly"   ng-model="(ContactPerson)+(ContactPersonSurname)"  />`
on the ng-model, it concatenates two fields and works fine, but i want to add space between (ContactPerson) and (ContactPersonSurname) using angular. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you provide expressions inside ng-model directive you will get an `[ngModel:nonassign]` error, In [Angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign) they clearly states that

> This error occurs when expression the ngModel directive is bound to is a non-assignable expression.
>   Always make sure that the expression bound via ngModel directive can be assigned to.

**Solution:**
Create a new $scope variable someting like
`$scope.fullName = (ContactPerson)+ ' ' +(ContactPersonSurname);` then use this in your html as below.

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.name = "john";
      $scope.surName = "Doe";
      $scope.fullName = $scope.name + " " + $scope.surName;
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="fullName" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input field is readonly. So you can use expressins instead of binding model.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ContactPerson = 'foo';
    $scope.ContactPersonSurname = 'bar';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" class="step-input" readonly="readonly" value="{{ContactPerson}} {{ContactPersonSurname}}"  />
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem.